# Помогите задать жирный текст в php word

Tags: php, html, phpword

Добрый день!
Знаю вопрос звучит глупо, но подскажите как можно задать жирный текст
Использую PHPWord, генерирую документ по шаблону и в определенном месте нужно текст сделать жирным HTML-теги(strong, b) не срабатывают

```
$text = "<b>Привет, медвед!</b>";
```

Но срабатывают спецсимволы

```
$text = "&#8226;Привет, медвед";
```

Как можно справиться с этой ситуацией?

Спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633028/phpword-bold-certain-words-on-a-line

Comment: Данный способ не помог, я использую шаблон